# Multi-instancing a project with extensive use of globals

Tags: vb.net, global-variables

We have a fairly robust program developed in Visual Basic .NET, and we've created an API which essentially represents the entire program as a single object. This works quite well and we've been using it for years--but now a project's come up where we really could use multiple instances of this.

The problem is that the codebase has extensive references to a global variable (gSvcMgr) in a Startup module. How can I make multiple instances of this object reference a different variable? Can I use namespaces? Or the Shadows keyword?

I can describe the structure further if I've been unclear, or if the specifics might help.

While refactoring the globals isn't out of the question if it's the only option, we have a very large code base, and only a few developers.

Thank you!

Comment: Um... create each instance of the object on its own thread, and mark all global variables as [thread-static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: Don't know why you didn't just mark this as an answer, but thanks for the suggestion. I can't tell if this will work on a Module variable or not, but I will try it tomorrow when I get to the office.

Comment: I only didn't make this an answer because I'm completely unsure it will work and whether or not it is even recommended.

Comment: So we ended up refactoring to just pass the previously global reference down to everyone who needed it. Thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create each instance of your application object in a separate [Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxk374d9.aspx) using [AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnWrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx).  That will create each instance of the option it a different domain where which will have its own copy of the shared global data and will not touch each other.

Using app domains will however come with a performance cost - all method calls will be [marshaled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29) (read copied) between the app domains.  You will also have to derive your application object from [MashalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

See this [blog post](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2010/09/01/using-appdomains-to-make-non-threadsafe-code-threadsafe.aspx) for an example of using app domains to solve a similar issue to yours.

Comment: Ooh this may be very useful. This issue will likely only apply to this single project, so I don't think the performance hit will be too enormous of a concern. I'll give GSerg's quick-fix a shot first, and see what this can do for me if I have trouble. Thanks for the clear answer and all the references!

Comment: I ended up just doing the refactor. This is probably the best alternative I found, so thanks for the pointer. You get the check (being the only answer, and being a good suggestion)